# How to change coordinates/polygon from geojson in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

Assuming I have a variable "mypoly" that was a polygon generated from geojson and added to the map in leaflet, assuming I have a new coordinate string:

```
[[[x,y],[x,y],[x,y],[x,y],[x,y],[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]]]
```

What is the best way to make it so that I can change the coordinates of "mypoly"? I don't think there is a mypoly.setCoordinates(....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no setCoordinates but there is [setLatLngs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline-setlatlngs)

Remember L.Polygon is a L.Polyline. So it inherits its methods.